# UIPageViewController: show specific pages on specific dates

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uipageviewcontroller

From the UIPageViewController template provided by Apple I'm working on creating a digital block calendar, meaning that the app will consist of 365 pages of content, and when it opens I want it to show the page according to today's date. Now I'm quite familiar with NSDates and such, but much less with the UIPageViewController. Before getting myself into unnecessary trouble, what would seem the most straightforward way of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using this gitHub project called RTSPagedView.  First, it will dequeue and reuse views, so you only have a few views in memory (not 365).  As a view appears, it dequeues like a UITableView, and fills the next offscreen view with the next index of data in your array.

Second, use the setContentOffset method to scroll to a particular date (pageWidth * index).  However, you might want to play with that 365 threshold.  My guess is you could get away with something like 30 in cache, and load a new data source as the user gets close to an edge of your dates.

RTSPagedView: http://github.com/rplasman/RTSPagedView/

Comment: Thanks. However, i would like to stick to the 'curling paper'-animation of the UIPageViewController. Do you still think this project is the best starting point?